# Can my test haproxy server load balence a production server?

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I have an haproxy server which balances the load between three production servers using (for reasons I don't understand) the *source* algorithm. One of them keeps getting into a state where although it is not working properly, haproxy doesn't spot this. Consequently my website goes down for some people.

I have a test haproxy server which balances the load on some test servers. I would like to test some other `haproxy.cfg` to see whether the faulty server can be detected. However, the fault is intermittent and I cannot reproduce it - I have to wait until it happens naturally.

I am thinking that I could test the test haproxy server by letting it balance loads on the faulty production server. But this would have to happen at the same time as the production haproxy server, so that the fault can occur. I could then see whether the test haproxy server (with a different `haproxy.cfg`) has spotted it.

But, as a complete beginner, I don't know whether letting two haproxy servers balance the load on the same (production) server is possible/sensible/a very stupid idea indeed.

Comment: Ah, I have thought of a way round this: When it next occurs, I could remove the faulty server from the production haproxy `haproxy.cfg` and add it to the test haproxy `haproxy.cfg` and then, because the faulty server will stay in its faulty state until I sort it out, play till my heart is content. But it would be nice to know the answer to my question  anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem having two haproxy instances pointing to the same set of servers. No need to wait until it fails to reconfigure your test one.